# Can't create table 'xxx' (errno: 150)

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

Here are the relevant sql statements:

```
CREATE TABLE VISIT
(
Date_of_Visit           DATE                NOT NULL,
Patient_Username        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
Doctor_Username     VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
Diastolic_Blood_Pressure    INTEGER,
Systolic_Blood_Pressure INTEGER,
Billing_Amount      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (Date_of_Visit, Doctor_Username, Patient_Username),
FOREIGN KEY(Doctor_Username) REFERENCES DOCTOR(Username) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(Patient_Username) REFERENCES PATIENT(Username) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE PRESCRIPTION
(
    Patient_Username    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
Doctor_Username VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,   
Date_of_Visit       DATE                NOT NULL,
Medicine_Name   VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
Notes           VARCHAR(255),
Dosage      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
Duration        INTEGER         NOT NULL,
Is_Ordered      BOOLEAN,
PRIMARY KEY (Patient_Username, Doctor_Username, Date_of_Visit, Medicine_Name),
FOREIGN KEY(Patient_Username, Doctor_Username, Date_of_Visit) 
REFERENCES VISIT(Patient_Username, Doctor_Username, Date_of_Visit) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Patient, Doctor, Visit tables have been created correctly. But when creating prescription, it gives me

## 1005 - Can't create table 'cs4400_Group_52.PRESCRIPTION' (errno: 150)

Any idea why?

EDIT: patient and doctor table creation sql

```
CREATE TABLE PATIENT
(
    Username        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Password        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Name            VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Home_Phone      INTEGER         NOT NULL,   
    Date_of_Birth       DATE                NOT NULL,
    Annual_Income   INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Gender      ENUM('M','F')           NOT NULL,
    Address     VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    Work_Phone      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Contact_Name    VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Contact_Phone   INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Weight      INTEGER,
    Height          INTEGER,
    Card_No     INTEGER,
    PRIMARY KEY(Username),
    FOREIGN KEY(Card_No) REFERENCES PAYMENT_INFO(Card_No) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE DOCTOR
(
    Username        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Password        VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    First_Name      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Last_Name       VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Date_Of_Birth       DATE                NOT NULL,
    Work_Phone      INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Speciality      VARCHAR(20)     NOT NULL,
    Room_Number INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    Home_Address    VARCHAR(255)        NOT NULL,
    Average_Rating  INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    License_Number  INTEGER         NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Username)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

[image]

Comment: Probably a problem with your foreign keys. Can you post your `DOCTOR` table?

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: Just a guess, change the order of the fields in the Foreign key to match the order of the fields in the VISIT table's primary key

Comment: @Alex it says server version: 5.1.69 protocol version: 10

Comment: @Sparky you are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two errors:

A) in CREATE TABLE VISIT need to INDEX (Date_of_Visit, Patient_Username, Doctor_Username),

B) need change the order of the fields in the Foreign key to match the order of the fields in the VISIT table's primary key @Sparky

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that the field order of the foreign key did not match the field order of the related table's primary key...

```
 CREATE TABLE VISIT
    (
     <fields>
    PRIMARY KEY (Date_of_Visit, Doctor_Username, Patient_Username)


 CREATE TABLE PRESCRIPTION
 ( 
   <fields>
 REFERENCES VISIT(Patient_Username, Doctor_Username, Date_of_Visit)
```

The OP solved the issue by adjusting the field order in the VISIT references